# UI block while rendering data in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, user-interface, concurrency

I have a side bar and a container when i click on any link on side bar the container loads its component and renders its data.
on clicking sidebar links there is an animation happen on side bar which stuck when data being rendered i figured out while rendering all UI stop responding for some milliseconds how to solve these type of problems any help ???
I have tried using `React.Memo()` to optimize rendering but none work i thought its single threaded issue but dont know how to solve it
[See Animation Stuck when data being Rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkXQS.gif)

Comment: Hello, it would be helpful if you can share an example  (like a sand Box ).

Comment: @antoineso please check img attachment i have updated